# Laptop Failing to Record System Audio

Tags: audio, drivers, audio-recording

I have been recording videos for a while now using my Lenovo T430 Laptop (Windows 7 64-bit) with no errors; but now I cannot record audio. I usually used Camtasia Studio 8 to record my videos due to it's ability to record webcam, system audio, and mic audio simultaneously.

I think my audio driver had occasional crashes because when recording audio, sometimes my computer would lock up for a few seconds and then my computer would run fine and I could still record video but all audio was gone... From that point I could not hear any audio until I restarted my computer, and when replaying my recording the audio was saved until the lock-up then there was no sound for the remaining film.

Although annoying I tolerated this bug because I had to, but I think the latest crash did permanent damage. My computer is now no longer able to record system audio on anything; I have searched around and found that I don't have the "Stereo Mix" Realtek driver, but some people say that is just a windows error. I never had to install any drivers when I started recording on this laptop so I do not know why that would be the problem but I just wanted to explain all the information for a more accurate understanding of my problem.

Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you searched Lenovo's site for the latest drivers for your laptop? Also see if any BIOS updates are available.

Comment: @Kara: Yes, I searched lenovo's website for the latest stereo mix realtek driver; but when I installed it and replaced my old one it caused a bunch of errors and my computer became very slow so I had to restore it back before I installed it.